# How to use virtualenv inside a folder?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I try to use `virtualenv` inside a folder using the command `virtualenv .` and getting the error `-bash: virtualenv: command not found`. However, I installed `virtualenv` using pip `pip installed virtualenv` and also, upgraded it earlier with `sudo pip install virtualenv`.

How to use `virtualenv` properly ? I'm following a tutorial and they seems doing the same and gets away with it. I'm a Java developer with beginner knowledge of Python and working to improve it.

Comment: Why  `-1`  for a valid question that I don't find the answer ? Show me duplicate with answer that works in this case, please.

Comment: -1 likely because the problem exists elsewhere if the command is not found. Typical [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple
Just goto environment folder
Try: `Scripts/activate`
This will activate the environment
Try:`Scripts/deactivate`
This will deactivate current environment

Comment: Where is the `environment` folder ?